# How to pass string value via putString in Java

Tags: java, android, string

In my activity, I'm not able to access a string via putString in Java. Here is the code:

```
private void setButtonListeners()
{
    SharedPreferences sp = this.getSharedPreferences("favs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    Editor editor = sp.edit();
    editor.putString("HelloActivity", "com.example.hiapp.HelloActivity, com.example.hiapp.R.string.byebye");
    editor.commit();
}
```

When I start the activity, everything is ok but instead of showing the name of the string, it just shows the location of the string: com.example.hiapp.R.string.byebye

Any ideas about this? I'm not familiar with the use of putString. Thank you

**EDIT: screenshot**

[image]

**EDIT 2**

As you can see in the question, the problem is with:

```
 editor.putString("HelloActivity", "com.example.hiapp.HelloActivity, com.example.hiapp.R.string.byebye");
```

Definition:

```
putString (String key, String value)
```

The problem is with string value. It is composed by: com.example.hiapp.HelloActivity which is the name of the activity the button makes you access to.
And: com.example.hiapp.R.string.byebye which is the string name I want to show. THIS is the only error, I don't know hot to show any string without modifying the putString.

As you can see in the image, first it displays the String, and the there's a button using com.example.hiapp.HelloActivity. But that string is not showing its name, it is showing its location

Comment: Screenshot is not clear enough as you talk about location of string. Please explain in brief.

Comment: The aim is to add to favourites an activity. So in that activity I press and "Add" button so that in another activity I'm able to access the bookmarked activity (which is created in a list) via button. Here what I'm showing is the code for the "being bookmarked" activity

Comment: and what it has to do with String's full location?

Comment: The list is created and each item shows a string which identifies the activity bookmarked and a button to aaccess it. What doesn't work is displaying the name of the string

Comment: I want to write the string's location to show it in the list, next to the corresponding button

Comment: Still not working... What I mean is that putString needs the location of the activity to pass it to the button, not to show it. And also needs the location of the string, just to display it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61830/discussion-between-mysticmagic-and-isaias).

Comment: update your code where you set string name

Answer (score 0):

It should be :

```
private void setButtonListeners()
{
    SharedPreferences sp = this.getSharedPreferences("favs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    Editor editor = sp.edit();
    editor.putString("HelloActivity", getString(R.string.byebye));
    editor.commit();
}
```

This should work now.

Comment: Thank you. I tell you the same thing as MysticMagic

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
editor.putString("HelloActivity", "com.example.hiapp.HelloActivity, com.example.hiapp.R.string.byebye");
```

to

```
editor.putString("HelloActivity", getResources().getString(R.string.byebye));
```

or

```
editor.putString("HelloActivity", getString(R.string.byebye));
```

To include location, too, you can try this:

```
editor.putString("HelloActivity", getString(R.string.byebye) + " and Location: com.example.hiapp.R.string.byebye");
```

You are putting location. So its showing location.

Refer [getResources()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getResources()) and [getString()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString(int))

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, but I forgot to say that there's a button next to the string, so I need to indicate location and resource of string. I edit and add an image of the Activity

Comment: I am not sure, I understand what you mean. Waiting for edited question.

Comment: @SweetWisherツ The button needs the location via putString and the String to show a name for the list item

Comment: Please be clear with your requirement first... @Isaías